# How to achieve superscript on rapahel text

Tags: jquery, text, svg, raphael, superscript

How to achieve superscript on rapahel text
When a user types in textarea i am getting its value and updating the raphael text using   `rapaheltext.attr({text:textarea.value})` 
now if somebody types 2^n i want to  be like **2ⁿ** on the rapahel text like wise for all the alphabets be it 2^x ,2^o etc

Comment: what is wrong with my answer? at least give me a vote if you are not excepting it.

Comment: Dude ,,,i am new to this and my reputaion seems to be 1 ,,i tried to upvote but it isnt allowing ,,however your answer is not complete try typing 2^n + 3^x...

Comment: that is why I mentioned in my answer "Of course this is a simple example, so you need to adjust the code to you liking or according to you application."

Answer (score 2):

OK, I did some research for adding superscripts and subscripts to a Raphael text...but no luck. `Raphael.text()` gets only string type does not interpret `html` to string.

So, I have got different solution that works just fine. Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/148/)**

In the DEMO when you enter a text without `^` and with `^`, you can see that it works. Of course this is a simple example, so you need to adjust the code to you liking or according to you application.

```
var paper = new Raphael("canvas");
var r = paper.rect(75,10,150,80,5).attr({fill:'yellow'});

$('#btn').click(function() 
{
    var text = document.getElementById('ttt').value;
    var pos = text.indexOf('^');

    if (text.indexOf('^') > 0)
    {
        // we want to create superscript 
        var a = text.substring(0, pos);
        var b = text.substring(pos + 1);

        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = a + '<sup>' + b + '</sup>';
    }
    else
    { 
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;    
    }
});
```

What I did was to create an empty `div` with absolute positioning and set it's position to the middle of the i.e. `Raphael.rect()`. The purpose of this div would be to act like `Raphael.text()`.

This gives us ability to use **`innerHTML`** and set the text inside the `div` by using **HTML's `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags**.

***Good luck***

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is using two text elements. One for 2 and one for n.
For example:

```
var paper = new Raphael("canvas");
var text = paper.text(10,20, "2");
var text2 = paper.text(10 + text.getBBox().width, 15, "n");
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/149/))

You also can feed Raphael elements similar to a DOM element. Raphael's text element will be split to two tspan if we have an **\n** character in input text.

Hope this help.

Comment: What i have done for now is Using Unicode characters ,,replacing ^n with its superscript Unicode....that works pretty well for few alphabets ...but Unicode for all the characters doenot seem to exist..!

Comment: I tried with some Vietnamese character, I work well. Can you give me your demo text?

Comment: See if the character Just after ^ is n then i replace it with its unicode like  (character == "n")?"\u207F" :(character == "0")?"\u2070"  Like wise i could only use it fo few 4-5 alphabets not for all 26 alphabets ,,i hace searched a lot but could not find for all the alphabets

Comment: OMG, why dont you convert that character id to its real character.

Comment: Its not about the way i am replacing. ,,Theres no  superscipt unicode for all the alphabets...only for a few exist..!

Comment: I can understand your pain now. I saw something here: 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=superscript&preview=entity
But I think you can use my solution for most of character.